# How do you reverse the result of using a wrong code

Tags: r

I am a new R user.

I used this code to format date data type:

```
daily_activity$date <- as.Date(daily_activity$date, format = "%m%d%Y")
```

All the dates were replaced with NA

What went wrong and how can I get the dates back in the data frame?

Comment: Looks like you will need to re-create `daily_activity` and re-run the first of those calls again.  In the future, creating a new variable e.g., `daily_activity$date2 <- as.Date(...)` is safer and will eliminate these kinds of problems.

Comment: Thank you for the response and the advice